# What's an "additional tie breaker" for Perl 6 longest token matching?

Tags: regex, raku

The [docs for Perl 6 longest alternation in regexes punt to Synopsis 5](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Longest_Alternation:_|) to document the rules for [longest token matching](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Longest-token_matching). There are three rules if different alternatives would match a substring of the same length:

- The longest declarative prefix breaks the tie
- The highest specificity breaks the tie
- "If it's still a tie, use additional tie-breakers."
- The left most alternation finally wins

It's that third rule that I'm curious about.

Comment: As I read it there are only 3 rules, and "the leftmost alternation wins" is one (the only?) additional tiebreaker

Comment: It's a design document. It probably means "let's leave that to the implementation"

Comment: I think @Aaron is right; that interpretation is supported by the fact that there are only three bullet points. The text under each bullet point could have been indented for clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means by additional tie-breakers, and I'm not sure if there are any. I would suspect not. It could have been put in there for “wiggle room”.

Comment: This is perhaps obvious, but "leftmost alternation wins" must be understood to be leftmost in MRO and only then leftmost textually/lexically within each grammar in an inheritance chain. In other words, if there's a file called `tie-together.pm6` containing `grammar tie { token TOP { <foo> }; proto token foo {*}; token foo:alt<A> { a . { say 'A' } } }; grammar tie-too is tie { token foo:alt<B> { a . { say 'B' } }` and a script `use tie-together; tie-too.parse: 'aa';`, then stdout displays `B` because `tie-too` comes before`tie` (so `tie-too` is leftmost) in the MRO resolving the `.parse` call.

Comment: I think the answer is "no one knows but we will all guess".

Comment: This may again be obvious, but another tie-breaker, also mentioned in the design doc, is that the user may manually force a failure if the wrong one is tried first. This naturally falls out of the way matching works.

Comment: According to [the LTM design doc](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Longest-token_matching) that's linked from the LTM user doc, manual failing is the only mechanism available to reliably deterministically tie break if A) a tied set of LTM alternatives for some match are from a grammar defined in one compilation unit that is [`augment`](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/augment)ed in one or more other compilation units and B) neither prefix length nor specificity resolve a tie.

Answer (score 0):

First the way the text is organized makes clear that the behaviour of the implementation must be deterministic (not random).

Second - and more important - describing the exact behaviour of existing implementations could fill an entire, hard-to-understand page as every corner case has to be described. In addition such a specification would limit degrees of freedom of the implementation. Let's assume some implementation supports a "fastest implementation" flag. Such an implementation can use unspecified parts to make short-cuts. So leaving the behaviour unspecified resp. restricted to the minimum has some advantages.