# proto token candidates ordering

Tags: regex, grammar, raku

How does perl6 decide which `proto` `token` to match against first?

The below code works as expected, it matches the string `1234`, and `Grammar::Tracer` shows that the first token matched against is `s:sym<d>`, which makes sense since it's the longest token.

However, if I changed a literal to token, for example, changing `token` `three` form `'3'` to `<digit>`, it fails to match, and `Grammar::Tracer` shows that `s:sym<b>` is being matched against first.

Moving `s:sym<d>` to the top, matches the string in both cases, but what is the explanation for that behavior?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
no precompilation;
use Grammar::Tracer;

grammar G {

  token TOP { <s> }

  proto token s { * }

  token s:sym<a> { <one> }
  token s:sym<b> { <one> <two> }
  token s:sym<c> { <one> <two> <three> }
  token s:sym<d> { <one> <two> <three> <four> }

  token one   { '1' }
  token two   { '2' }
  token three { '3' }
  token four  { '4' }
}

my $g = G.new;

say $g.parse: '1234';
```

```
# Output: Match
# token three { '3' }

TOP
|  s
|  |  s:sym<d>
|  |  |  one
```

```
# Output No Match
# token three { <digit> }

TOP
|  s
|  |  s:sym<b>
|  |  |  one
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How does perl6 decide which proto token to match against first?

It uses ["Longest alternation" logic](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Longest_alternation:_|). In your (well presented!) case the relevant deciding factors are as follows.

> First, select the branch which has the *longest declarative prefix*.

So the first thing to focus on is that it's not "longest token" but longest *declarative prefix*, the *start* of a pattern that contains nothing but contiguous "declarative" "atoms".

A `3` is a declarative atom.

A `<foo>` may or may not be; it depends on what it includes.

I haven't found clear official documentation identifying which *built in* patterns are declarative and which are not but it looks like all the ones declared with a slash, eg `\d`, are declarative whereas all the ones declared in the form form `<foo>`, eg `<digit>`, are not. 
(Note in particular that the built in `<ws>` pattern is *not* declarative. Given that spaces after atoms in `rules` are converted to `<ws>`, this means the first such space terminates the declarative prefix of that rule.)

So a `<digit>` atom isn't part of a declarative prefix and instead terminates a prefix.

> Moving `s:sym<d>` to the top, matches the string in both cases, but what is the explanation for that behavior?

Because with the change of `<three>` to call `<digit>` you've changed your rules to have three that tie for longest declarative prefix (`<one> <two>`). So [other tie-breaking rules are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943078/whats-an-additional-tie-breaker-for-perl-6-longest-token-matching).

If all else fails in those tie-breaking rules to pick a winner, then the last "left-most" rule is selected, which, [ignoring inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943078/whats-an-additional-tie-breaker-for-perl-6-longest-token-matching#comment86947150_49943078), means the rule that comes first lexically.